# Why do the Gaussian rationals make these patterns?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, gaussian-integers, farey-sequences

I was looking for a cool thing to visualize, when I found [this picture](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreducibleFraction.html) on Wolfram MathWorld. I obtained the image below by taking all integers $a, b, c, d$ in a given range (between $-15$ and $15$ here). I then calculated $\frac{a+bi}{c+di}$ and plotted it to give this image.

[image]

If I'm correct, these complex irreducible rationals are called the "Gaussian rationals". One thing that immediately pops out here are the empty regions with flower-like shapes.

It kind of reminds me of the [Farey sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6i1D.png), and it seems that the gaps here line up well with the gaps in the Farey sequences. There are gaps at $i$, $-i$, $1$, and $-1$, and smaller gaps at $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{i}{2}$, etc.

My question is - why? Why are there gaps at regular intervals in this picture, and why are there gaps in the Farey series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the Gaussian version of "rational numbers with small denominator can't be too close together". In the real rationals, this is just due to the inequality $|\frac wx-\frac yz| = \frac{|wz-xy|}{xz} \ge \frac1{xz}$ (when $\frac wx\ne\frac yz$ of course).

In the Gaussians, the distance between $\frac{a+bi}{c+di}$ and $\frac{e+fi}{g+hi}$ will be at least $\frac1{\sqrt{(c^2+d^2)(g^2+h^2)}}$. So there's a gap around each Gaussian rational (when comparing to other Gaussian rationals of small height), but those gaps are more pronounced when $c^2+d^2$ is small (such as $\pm1$ and $\pm i$).

Comment: Okay, but do you have any papers or sources that confirm this claim? I want to  read more if so.

Comment: You can confirm it yourself: \begin{align*}
\biggl| \frac{a+bi}{c+di} - \frac{e+fi}{g+hi} \biggr| &=
\biggl| \frac{(a+bi)(g+hi)-(e+fi)(c+di)}{(c+di)(g+hi)} \biggr| \\
&= \frac{|(-ce+df+ag-bh)+i(-de-cf+bg+ah)|}{|(c+di)(g+hi)|} \ge \frac1{|c+di||g+hi|}
\end{align*}